# When is it best to create a meta table?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, lumen

Recently I find myself creating meta tables for most of my main tables.

**For example**, my user table contains a password, email, and ID, as well as some timestamps. But things like where the user is from, their profile picture, or their favourite colour I store in a user_meta table. Some details, such as contacts, I store as a JSON value (array) in the meta table, with the key being `contacts` and the value being a JSON array with contact details.

My reasoning is that it makes it easier for me to change the front end and add features/details without having to play around with the server-side of things.

That being said, I'm worried that I have to fetch the meta table often which impacts performance. In the case outlined above, I have to fetch the meta table each time I display a list of users, just so that I can get their profile picture.

When is it better to create a separate key-value meta table instead of just using specific columns for that?

Comment: I'd store profile pic, favorite color, location, etc. as columns in the `users` table. I would **not** store contacts that way - they should be a separate table with a relationship in place.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is not necessarily incorrect, however, "meta" table is not the correct way, in relational terms, to describe what you are looking to achieve.

There is nothing saying you couldn't have a user_profile with 1:1 relationship with the user and additional tables with different types of relationships - one to many for example.

On the JSON side of things: your user contact data will typically not change in structure so you could just create a user_contacts table with a 1:n assuming one or more contacts per user.  I also wouldn't personally be a fan of suffixing a table with "meta" to denote some self referencing as it is too vague to describe what might be the contents (especially if you also have one or more columns with JSON data types).  I would opt for JSON data type in the event that the structure will change often enough to warrant it being useful.

If the structure of your user data is in flux often enough you may want to consider a NoSQL database or potentially you could have a single "meta" table, as you describe, with a couple of JSON data types where the structure of that data is changeable and you don't need to unpack the data often enough for it to be a pain...

To expand a little on this.  There are no hard and fast rules but typically, if your table is going to store lots of rows, you could keep it compact and contain only the data that you are accessing most often there.  One reason for having a 1:1 user_profile table would be that you may only access this once when the user logs in and you may want to cache that data and only retrieve it again should the user update this.  A lot of this will be governed by the usage and architecture of your app itself (i.e. each app will be different).

With that said providing you don't have an unwieldy number of columns it is perfectly fine to have a single table to contain all associated data with a given model.

A little more expansion based on your request below re: my comment on meta in the context of SQL.  For example metadata would typically describe the table and it's column (i.e. the collation, character set, column types, lengths and other properties etc.).  In theory you are not naming the table incorrectly but it could be a little confusing.

Comment: Great thorough answer! 

Really I'm afraid of having way too many rows in the User_profile table that'll hurt performance.

I see now how I could store contacts in a separate table. I think you're right that this is a good use case for NoSQL, but that's something for some reason I'm having a hard time understanding. As a side note, could you expand on when the term 'meta' is used in relation to a db?

Comment: @Michał Facebook stores billions of rows in MySQL. As long as you've got proper indexes, having lots of rows shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @ceejayoz which gets me thinking how easy is it for them to create a new data field on us to show on the front end in the user profile. Say they wanted to show "Favourite Floating Tesla " alongside "Religious Beliefs", would that be a simple case of just adding a new key of `favourite_tesla` and a value of `The red one` to a pre-existing key-value table, or would it require them to add columns and build new tables?

Comment: They have quite a bit of interesting info at https://www.facebook.com/MySQLatFacebook/. Do note that they use non-SQL databases in conjunction with MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

> When is it better to create a separate key-value meta table instead of just using specific columns for that?

A meta table is best when data-types the application needs to perform certain actions may vary over time, or when you have a large number of null-able fields that bear no strong correlation to the model/table.

WordPress has a meta table for users and posts. This is because WordPress was created to be highly customizable by themes and the developers have no knowledge of what each theme would need to function properly.

Another use case could be if you are creating an omni-messaging app like MessageBird where you have various channels like WhatsApp, Telegram and SMS to push messages through. Each channel may have different requirements for the data needed to send a message, and new channels may come up in the future with their own data requirements. So it'll make sense to use a meta table to cater to future needs.

In terms of impacting performance, this really depends on the what exactly your application needs to do. For some use cases, the performance impact can be negligible (e.g. if the action being carried out is occurring only on the server and does not need to send out data to a front-end). But even if it is not, you could always cache the data using a NoSQL service like Redis, eliminating the need to fetch the data from the database on every request.

Comment: Straightforward!